# WebStorm: Is it possible to move the split-horizontally divider with keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I frequently use the "split horizontally" command when setting up editor tabs in WebStorm / IntelliJ IDEA.  I usually want the right panel at about 30% and the left panel at 70%... but it defaults to 50-50.  I am a keyboard-centric user and I am getting sick of reaching for the mouse every time I want to move the divider just to set up YET AGAIN.  I do this many, many times throughout the day (each time I open a new issue with a new context) so it's not so trivial.

What can I do to speed this up?  Is it possible to move the divider with the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Tab Shifter for IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7475-tab-shifter) plug-in.

The actions you need are:

- stretch split left/right
- stretch split up/down (no default shortcuts, assign in Keymap)

There is a request to have this feature without a plug-in, feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-67379](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67379) Change splitter position via keyboard

Comment: Perfect - the "stretch split left/right" is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Tip: stretch split up/down is also available but not configured with a shortcut key by default